# Почему возникает ошибка сессии в .NET 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, .net-6

Использую Blazor Server. Возникает проблема при попытке сохранить в куки капчу. Вот ошибка:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The session cannot be established after the response has started.  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession.Set(String key, Byte[] value)
```

```
public string GetCaptchaImage()
{
    var code = generateCaptchaCode();

    var imageInBase64 = generateImageBase64(Width, Height, code);

    httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session.Set("CaptchaCode", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
    return imageInBase64;
}
```

В конфигурации сервиса я уже настроил сессию:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(c =>
{
    c.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    c.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});  
app.UseSession();
```

В чем проблема и как можно исправить данную ошибку?